# Cannot be open a Xcode project which is created by CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake, xcode4.5

I have a C++ project which created in Visual Studio 2010 IDE. Now I want to continue my development in Xcode IDE with GCC in Mac Platform. So I created an Xcode project using CMake to continue my development. 
But after I created Xcode project, I tried to open my project (by double-clicking .xcodeproj file), then It's saying an error message that is "Project /Users/../Desktop/MyProj/Build/MyProj.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed". 
What could I do to solve this problem? If anybody having some idea regarding this, please reply on this thread. 
Xcode version: 4.6.3 CMake Version: 2.8-11

Answer (score 3):

Problem could be in your CMakeLists.txt. Once you generated, you can open the .xcodeproj in a text editor and check for the incompatibility.

If you can generate the project files for other IDEs like Visual Studio, it must work.